# solicitação AJAX jquery gerando um array com apenas um campo carregado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

eu tenho um array de objetos - JSON:

```
[
{
 "nome": "Luis",
 "numero": 14
},
{
 "nome": "Pedro",
 "numero": 12
},
{
  "nome": "Maria",
  "numero": 1
}
]
```

como faço uma solicitação AJAX (jquery) que me retornasse somente os campos "nome":

```
[{"nome": "Luis"},{"nome": "Pedro"},{"nome": "Maria"}]
```

ou

```
["Luis","Pedro","Maria"]
```

eu tentei com um parametro em jquery:

```
var parametro = {"nome":"Pedro"};    
$.get("[URL]", parametro, [function]);
```

e claro que ele só retornava um elemento de nome: Pedro. Alguém sabe como retornar um array (de preferencia um array de strings)? obrigado.

Comment: Cara acho que isso não é possível, quando faz a solicitação o json vem do jeito que foi formatado pelo back-end. Terá que tratar isso no front, o que tbm está bem simples!

Comment: Como @LeAndrade andrade falou, ou vc altera o back-end retornando apenas os nomes ou faz como a resposta abaixo indicou.

Comment: ok. é que o retorno será "pesado" no segundo campo. aqui só tem um int, mas a ideia é pegar uma string monstro e dezenas de objetos. pensei em algo que me desse performance.

Answer (score 0):

Eu iteraria sobre o array pegando apenas o nome e adicionando em um novo array de nomes. Da seguinte forma:

```
var names = [];
$.get('http://urlEmquestao', function(response){
   for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      names.push(response[i].nome);
   }
});
```